# При импорте из Excel в блокнот меняется формат даты

Tags: excel, vba

Импортирую данные из эксель в тхт через VBA. но почему-то даты в блокноте стали сохраняться в другом формате. 
До этого всегда с этим кодом выгружал в тхт в формате dd.mm.yyyy, а  теперь mm/dd/yyyy. Код не менялся, а результат вдруг изменился.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

```
    Sub TxtUnloadPrep(SaveDir As String)

On Error Resume Next

Dim i As Long, ec As Long
Dim c As String, fArch As String, ArchDir As String
Dim s As Integer, l As Integer

'Unhide
Columns("A:AH").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Selection.ColumnWidth = 20

'Change all formula to val
FormulasToVal

'General format
'Cells.Select
'Selection.NumberFormat = "General"


'Transcription by column
For i = 1 To ec
    c = CStr(Cells(1, i).Value)

    'Max len 16 sym
    'Cut and add curent num of column to end
    l = 16 - Len(CStr(i))
    Cells(1, i).Value = Left(TranslitText(c), l) & CStr(i)

    'General format
    If Cells(2, i).NumberFormat <> "dd.mm.yyyy" Then
        Columns(i).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "Date"
    End If

Next i

'Prepare folder and path
If Right(SaveDir, 1) <> "\" Then
   SaveDir = SaveDir & "\"
End If


    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"

    Range("W:W,X:X").Select
    Range("X1").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0,0000000"

'Archive folder name for save
fArch = CStr(Year(Now)) & CStr(Month(Now)) & CStr(Day(Now)) & CStr(Hour(Now)) & CStr(Minute(Now)) & CStr(Second(Now))



'Check dir or create for current unload
ChkDir (SaveDir)
Dim a$
a = Cells(2, 34) 'a1 data
Fname = a & "_PTPP.txt"

'Check Arch dir
ArchDir = SaveDir & "\" & fArch & "\"
ChkDir (ArchDir)

'Replace all file from current dir to arch
MvFls vSrcFldr:=SaveDir, vDstFldr:=ArchDir

'Final path and file current unload
SaveDir = SaveDir & Fname

'SaveAs
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveDir, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Exit Sub
  End If

End Sub
Private Sub ChkDir(Pdir As String)
  On Error Resume Next
  If Len(Dir(Pdir, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MakeTreeDirectory Pdir
  End If
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
Sub MakeTreeDirectory(PathDir) 'создание дерева каталогов
'разбиваем путь на составные части
   PathArrray = Split(PathDir, "\")
'задаем имя диска
    NextDir = PathArrray(0)
'на всякий случай проверяем, есть ли такой диск
    If Dir(PathArrray(0), vbDirectory) = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
'в цикле создаем каталоги по заданному пути
    For n = 1 To UBound(PathArrray)
'задаем путь к очередному каталогу
        NextDir = NextDir & "\" & PathArrray(n)
'если каталог не существует, создаем его
        If Dir(NextDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir (NextDir)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Sub FormulasToVal()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
End Sub
Sub MvFls(vSrcFldr As String, vDstFldr As String)

    Dim strFile As String
    Dim Cnt As Long

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next

    strFile = Dir(vSrcFldr & "*.txt")

    Do While Len(strFile) > 0

        'If Date - Int(FileDateTime(vSrcFldr & strFile)) > 2 Then
            Cnt = Cnt + 1
            'Replace
            Name vSrcFldr & strFile As vDstFldr & strFile
            'Delete
            Kill vSrcFldr & strFile
        'End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Completed!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Изменились настройки или в Excel, или системные. Пропишите в коде *dd/mm/yyyy*

Comment: @vikttur Коллеги говорят что причина в какомто обновлении, который все делает по американски (формат). Прописывал в коде формат dd\mm\yyyy. не помогает.

Comment: И у меня обновления прошли... Попобуйте сохранить любую книгу с датой в ячейках (тектовый будет создан рядом с книгой) таким макросом (разделите код макроса по строкам): `Sub SaveTxt()
    Dim SaveDir As String
    
    SaveDir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\1.txt"
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveDir, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub` Если даты не поменяют формат, перед сохранеием добавьте строку `Columns("P:P").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` и еще раз проверьте создание *.txt*

Comment: не сработало...выгрузился, но форматы дат в блокноте американские.

Comment: Забавно что если сохранить как text (tab delimited) то нормальный формат...